# Изменить прозрачность/фон Windows консоли используя Python 3.5

Tags: python, windows, консоль, python-3.5

Помогите пожалуйста, как сделать прозрачность консоли и фон консоли средствами python 3.5 или какими-то сторонними библиотеками. Буду благодарен, консоль кстати windows 10/7/8

Answer (score 0):

Если вы имеете ввиду под консолью стандартный `idle`, то для смены фона необходимо выполнить следующее:

```
Options -> Configure IDLE -> Fonts / Tabs
```

Про прозрачность даже не подскажу.

Comment: Для консоли windows.